# Doe rcorr in the Hmisc package use one-sided or two-sided test by default?

Tags: r, correlation

Does `rcorr` in r Hmisc use a one- or two-sided test by default? Spearman was chosen as the correlation method. How can I choose one-sided or two-sided in `rcorr` function?

Comment: I am not aware of `rcorr` in `base`, and `?base::rcorr` returns *No documentation for ‘rcorr’ in specified packages and libraries:*. To which package you are referring? Is your Q w.r.t. to p-values? Have a look at `?cor` and `?cor.test`. The latter has an argument `alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater")`. Also, I suspect your question refers to R, and *RStudio* is irrelevant here. I deleted it. However, if whatever you have is two-sided, perhaps dividing by `2` helps.

Comment: Do you mean the function in the Hmisc package?

Comment: Yes, I mean the rcorr function in Hmisc package, which was used to analyze the matrix data with many pairs.

Comment: There is not really sided-ness in the test for H0: (rho == 0)  unless you mean you want to specify a directional test. But I'd assume it is the usual version.

Comment: Yes. By the way, the test I refer to is the significance test often related to one or two-sided.